# Problem with jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this table:

```
<table>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>Title
            <div class="action">hello</div>
        </td>    
        <td>Rorow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>Title
            <div class="action">hello</div>
        </td>  
        <td>Rorow</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I want to make the child  disappear when I hover over the row. So I made this but it selects all of the other actions as well:

```
$(".row").hover(
        function () {
            $(".action").css("visibility","hidden");
        },
        function () {
            $(".action").css("visibility","visible");
        }
    );
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this in pure CSS.

```
tr.row .action {
    display:block;
}

tr.row:hover .action {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I verified this with jsfiddle and works great.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm leaning towards no.  IE6 has issues with the hover selector.  Fortunately, I don't have access to a machine with IE6 to test it, but that's unfortunate in this case.  You may want to go with a JS solution just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you're telling every element with the class "action" to disappear when you hover over a row. Instead, you can use `this` to refer to the row that the cursor passed over, then find its child "action" element and hide it.

```
$(".row").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find(".action").hide();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find(".action").show();
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was browsing for child selectors and couldn't get them to work. :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply look for the class within the `.row` parent element by using `$(this)`:

```
$(".row").hover(
    function () {
        //$(this) refers to the row that received the hover event
        $(this).find(".action").hide();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find(".action").show();
    }
);
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kYT44/).